# TypeError: Can't convert 'type' object to str implicitly

Tags: python

I am new to python and I would like the result to be that the different strings in the file are replaced with the new average speed which the user inputs.
Thank you.

```
fvehicleowners = open('vehicle owners.txt','r').read()
number = int
averagespeed = input

line = fvehicleowners.split('\n')
num_lines = fvehicleowners.count
print('The number of owners registered are: ', num_lines)
print('The number of owners registered are: ', num_lines)

averagespeed = input('Enter the average speed: ')
for line in fvehicleowners:
    str.replace('XXXXXXX', averagespeed, number)

averagespeed1 = input('Enter the average speed1: ')
for line in fvehicleowners:
    str.replace('YYYYYYY', averagespeed1, number)

averagespeed2 = input('Enter the average speed2: ')
for line in fvehicleowners:
    str.replace('ZZZZZZZ', averagespeed2, number)

averagespeed3 = input('Enter the average speed3: ')
for line in fvehicleowners:`
    str.replace('AAAAAAA', averagespeed3, number)

averagespeed4 = input('Enter the average speed4: ')
for line in fvehicleowners:
    str.replace('BBBBBBB', averagespeed4, number)

averagespeed5 = input('Enter the average speed5: ')
for line in fvehicleowners:
    str.replace('CCCCCCC', averagespeed5, number)

averagespeed6 = input('Enter the average speed6: ')
for line in fvehicleowners:
    str.replace('DDDDDDD', averagespeed6, number)


averagespeed7 = input('Enter the average speed7: ')
for line in fvehicleowners:
    str.replace('EEEEEEE', averagespeed7, number)

fvehicleownerdata = open('vehicle owner data.txt','w')
fvehicleowners = fvehicleownerdata
```

Comment: where and when do you get your error?

Comment: line 13, in <module>
    str.replace('XXXXXXX', averagespeed, number)#This will replace the unique code in the file with the average speed
TypeError: Can't convert 'type' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare variables, eg by assigning them to `int`. But, if you do call a method or a built-in, you need to actually *call* it, with the calling parentheses: `int()`, `input()`. The same would true of `count`, except that the way to get the length of a list is by `len(lst)`, not `lst.count()`.

You will also have lots of trouble when you get to the string replace methods: you need to call them on the actual strings, not on the `str` class, and you need to assign them back to a variable afterwards:

```
new_string = old_string.replace('old_pattern', 'new_pattern')
```

Comment: I've added and tweaked my code to apply everything you have said but now when I run my code nothing happens and I do not even receive an error text.

Answer (score -1):

Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])
```